# clockwork motor output in joules formula

Tags: motors, power, energy-storage, engineering-general

I'm trying to understand the output of clockwork coils in joules or watts for different coils. You know the pullback car or windup pocket watch mechanism. I have heard it also called power in the barrel.

I found this below image as is the best approximation of the power output, but I don't know the coil size, or how to determine the size of a coil barrel for a particular out requirements.

Question, how to determine output of a clockwork motor of given sizes?

[image]

Comment: See http://www.spiral-spring.com/about_power_springs.html for an overview and http://www.scribd.com/doc/29044778/Spring-Design-Handbook for equations